# How do I rebuild case-subcase connection if corrupted parent case deleted on mobile?

Tags: commcare

The current workflow for dealing with blocked-sync due to corrupted case(s) on a mobile device is to delete the individual case.
If that case was a parent of already-created but not-synced subcases, how do I rebuild case-subcase connections?
There will be a significant impact if I can't rebuild these connections (caseslists, various filters, xpath expressions, parent-case case property references, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think the only way to repopulate those case-subcase relationships is through a case import of the corrupted cases. This is outlined in the documentation here https://confluence.dimagi.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20218117